# How to enable text pasting on start screen?

Tags: windows-8.1

Starting with Windows Vista, I have found the fact that pressing Start, in addition to displaying the start menu/screen, the input focus is set to a search box, which also executes commands and opens folders among many other useful things.

One operation I very commonly do, is to copy a path into the clipboard, press <kbd>Start</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. A new explorer window appears with the path I had pasted.

In Windows 8, the textbox is hidden. But if I press any key, including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, the textbox is displayed. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> displays the textbox and pastes the text, just as before.

However, on Windows 8.1, this no longer works! Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> on the start screen does nothing, and then my muscle memory presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which opens the first program (weather app, which I never actually open. I just glance at the information in the tile).

The textbox is still there. If I press any other key, it appears. Only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (and probably other chords) stopped displaying the search box.

This means that I have to change my years-old muscle memory to <kbd>Start</kbd> <kbd>Any key</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This is very annoying.

I wonder why this was removed. I can't see any usability problems with <kbd>Start</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>. However, I want to bring the old functionality back.

Does anybody have any idea how to bring it back?

Comment: Can you try this: Go to `Taskbar and Navigation Properties` and click all the last four checkboxes. This should make Win 8.1 open all programs when you click start, which should also enable search by default.

Comment: Where's the Any Key?

Comment: @edvinas.me I don't want to see all the programs by default~~~ I just want to be able to paste after I press Start. Your suggestion didn't work though...

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>] to search from anywhere. You don't need to go to the start screen. <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>] followed by [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>] will paste your link/directory and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> will open file explorer to get you there.